# How can I generate a 1 Hz clock from 50 MHz clock coming from an Altera board?

Tags: verilog, intel-fpga

I have an Altera DE2 board that outputs a 50 MHz clock and I'm trying to write a verilog module that can bring it down to 1 Hz. How can I do this?

Comment: Divide by 50 million?

Comment: @rogerrowland I saw that question before I posted mine but I didn't understand most of the answer so I figured I'd ask it again to get simpler answers.

Comment: @Swailem95 It would have been useful to add the link to that question in your question and to explain what it was you didn't understand. Just hoping that asking a dupe will get you a "simpler" answer is a bit of a gamble.

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty simple, we just need to build a big counter. We want our output clock to be 50 million times slower than our input clock. To generate a complete output cycle we need to toggle the output twice. Therefore we want to toggle the output every 25 million cycles.

In general the best type of counter to use for this sort of thing is a "count down to zero" counter. We will count down through the range from 24999999 (one less than 25 million) to zero, then repeat. Each time our counter hits zero we toggle the output. Our counter needs to be at least 25 bit to accomodate this range of values.

```
reg [24:0] counter;
output reg clkout;
input clkin
initial begin
    counter = 0;
    clkout = 0;
end
always @(posedge clkin) begin
    if (counter == 0) begin
        counter <= 24999999;
        clkout <= ~clkout;
    end else begin
        counter <= counter -1;
    end
end
```

Comment: Why 25 million? Also what does the line right after the if statement do?

Comment: Does my edit answer your questions?

Comment: It answers the first one, but I dont understand what the <= is doing. Is this just a relational operation that either returns true or false? How are you using it like a normal statement?

Comment: Why don't you learn some Verilog?

Comment: It's a nonblocking assignment. I think you need to get yourself a basic verilog book and work through it.

Comment: It is worth mentioning that the constants should really be declared as 25bit wide as well, e.g. ```25'd24999999``` and ```counter <= counter - 25'd1```. This is really just to avoid compiler warnings about truncation of signals.